# Maven build failure when running tests due to JVM crash

Tags: java, maven, jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, jvm-crash

I have a java project with thousand tests,

When I run the tests it ends as follows:

```
$ mvn surefire:test
. . . 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:49 h
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-17T06:29:55-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/921M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-cli) on project Mine: ExecutionException; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
[ERROR] Command was/bin/sh -c cd /home/projects/mine && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el7_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/projects/mine/target/surefire/surefirebooter5661758071622971420.jar /home/projects/mine/target/surefire/surefire7221142682471689181tmp /home/projects/mine/target/surefire/surefire_96350455888867423114tmp
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My maven configuration is as follows:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T16:10:27-04:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el7_3.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I tried to update maven or re-running tests with `-X` option but didn't find anything special. Any idea how to debug/approach this issue??

**Update**
I turns out the problem was related to the use of a newer version of some native code. I had to replace the files `.so` files for an older lib version to fix the problem.

Comment: Concur with @khmarbaise. Try updating the plugin version, 2.16 is way old (2013!) and many fixes have been made since then.. Might fix the problem entirely, or at least give you more clues as to the true nature of the issue.

Comment: it's not the plugin version the problem as my collegues who work on the same project doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Okay, start with an empty local repo on the machine having the issue. One or more of the artifacts could be corrupted, I've seen that happen before.

Comment: I've also tried this approach, I even tried from a a brand new server (OS freshly installed).